# How to configure Amplify Authenticator component for sign in using external identity provider (IdP)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

The Amplify `Authenticator` component makes it easy to integrate AWS Cognito user pool authentication into apps. However, by default, it doesn't display sign in options for external identity providers (IdPs).

I have searched the docs, but can only find examples on how to configure it for social provider sign-in, e.g. Facebook.

How can I configure it to sign-in using external IdP?

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator socialProviders={['amazon', 'apple', 'facebook', 'google']}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/configuration

Comment: Were you able to get to this?

Comment: No, it wasn't possible using `Authenticator`